# Send form object to page on location change

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, forms

I have a form in Angular. At the end, there is a multi-level object of results from the form. For example:

```
var form = {
  answer1: "something",
  answer2: {
    subAnswer2-1: "this",
    subAnswer2-2: "something else"
  }
};
```

The HTML form wrapper looks like this:

```
<form name="assessment" ng-submit="assessmentSubmit(form)">
</form>
```

Now, in my controller, I want to go to a new page with the `POST` data (form object). The new page is a `.php` file that processes the results into a PDF.

I can do the redirect like this, but how do I apply the form data?

```
$scope.assessmentSubmit = function(form){
  $window.location.href = 'convert-pdf.php';  
};
```

Comment: Is using the localstorage an option? Or better sessionstorage?

Answer (score 0):

Store the form object in the sessionStorage as follows:

First, inject the $window service in your controller. Then,

```
$window.sessionStorage['form'] = JSON.stringify(form);
```

After this, redirect and in your php file, retrieve the form object:

```
<script>
    var form_obj = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage['form']);
</script>
```

Comment: Will I be able to access that javascript variable with PHP?

Comment: no it is not possible. You can only use javascript to access sessionstorage. Another alternative is using a cookie which is available to both javascript(frontend) and php(backend)